# Is it possible to change a bar button background image while we click on it?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a barbuttonitem which i have customised using a custom button with an image. I want to change this image everytime after I click it. Like on and off. Once I click it it will show OFF image. Then again it will go ON image.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  In your target method just change out the UIBarButtonItem

```
- (void)toolbarButtonPressedAwesomeMethod {

    Do awesome stuff...

    // Change the button here…
    UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init…

    // Set it in the view
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bbi];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`yourButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];`

[UIBarItem Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)